# Difference between sp_refreshview and sp_recompile

Tags: sql, sql-server

What's the difference between this two commands?

Refreshview is only for views and recompile only for stored procedures? or there are some other differences?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered by reading the documentation corresponding to each stored procedure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-refreshview-transact-sql & https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-recompile-transact-sql

Answer (score 2):

**Both of these system procedure can be used on a view or table. However, they do very different things.**

`sp_refreshview 'MyView'` causes the metadata for a view to be refreshed. This means that any DDL changes (such as `ALTER`) to base tables will be reflected in the view. This is particularly important for views which use `select *`.

`sp_recompile 'MyView'` causes all procedures, triggers and functions which *reference* the view to be recompiled and get a new query plan. It does *not* update the metadata for the view: if the view's base tables have changed then the metadata will still be incorrect.

You can see the difference in this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bcf045744ba3135064ce8405ed315aef). Notice how the new column was shown only after `sp_refreshview` was executed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sp_refreshview. sp_recompile is only for triggers and stored procedures.

Comment: Why do you say "You should use sp_refreshview"?  The question doesn't state that a view needs to be refreshed, only what the difference is.  If a view needs to be refreshed then he should use sp_refreshview.  If a proc needs to be recompiled then he should use sp_recompile.