# Stored procedure not returning full data of view

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that returns data from a view.

It basically does a `SELECT` statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_VIEW...
```

Using .NET 4.6, I'm calling it with `ExecuteFunction`.

I modified the view adding a new column and the stored procedure is not returning the new column's data. All my .NET models are already working expecting the new data, but it is just returning the default value.

If I do a `SELECT *` directly in SQL Server it does return the new data.

I have tried refreshing the view, recompiling the stored procedure with no success.

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you replace `*` with the *actual columns* you need (which you should be doing anyway) what happens?

Comment: What is "ExecuteFunction"? What if you run the SP in SSMS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add columns to a table, the stored procedure *as parsed* will not be updated to reflect that. You need `EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule` to update it.

```sql
EXEC sp_refreshsqlmodule N'dbo.YourProcName';
```

Recompiling the *query plan* using `sp_recompile` will not help, as it does not update the parse tree, only the query plan created from it. See also [Difference between sp_refreshview and sp_recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587854/difference-between-sp-refreshview-and-sp-recompile/70408551#70408551)

---

As far as Entity Framework is concerned, you also need to update the model so that it brings back that data. So you need to `Update Model`, see [Entity Framework : How do you refresh the model when the db changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947511/entity-framework-how-do-you-refresh-the-model-when-the-db-changes)